# Azure Data Sync Bi-Directional Only Sync Downwards

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Sync Group created inside Azure Web Portal, with bi-directional sycn upwards and downwards to local PC, the sync group was running fine in past few weeks but today, it suddenly only sync downwards (download data from Azure SQL Database).

I've checked the sync log and it has no warning / errors. Even before it stop uploading data, the even log seems normal:

Sync completed successfully in 21.95 seconds.   Upload:   4 changes applied Download: 7 changes applied    For more information, provide tracing ID ‘2dfb1462-23bc-4acd-a9fb-4d9b2cd3143a’ to customer support.

Sync completed successfully in 21.61 seconds.   Upload:   22 changes applied    Download: 28 changes applied    For more information, provide tracing ID ‘dfaf910d-92b9-469a-ab24-6e52adc56361’ to customer support.

Sync completed successfully in 19.87 seconds.   Upload:   0 changes applied Download: 2 changes applied    For more information, provide tracing ID ‘e38afca8-d519-4c9e-8379-422a03b02050’ to customer support.

Sync completed successfully in 26.96 seconds.   Upload:   0 changes applied Download: 38 changes applied    For more information, provide tracing ID ‘1674233f-3b0e-4328-9ae1-353433ec3b7a’ to customer support.

and then it have no more upload forever...

Has anyone encountered this problem? I've tried restarting local PC, SQL database and the sync agent, but still no help. Thanks!

Updates:
I've enabled the client side SQL Sync Agent logging, and here's the log during each sync:

```
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling PutRequest
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher started. Waiting
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:20. GetRequest finished. RequestId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
CommandAndControlClient 8/4/2014 17:25:21  id:CommandAndControlClient_GetRequest, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, taskId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
CommandAndControlClient 8/4/2014 17:25:21  id:CommandAndControlClient_AckRequest, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, taskId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
ClientRequestHandler 8/4/2014 17:25:21  id:ClientRequestHandler_Request, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, taskId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, serializedRequest:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SyncRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PostActionSucceededWork xsi:nil="true" />
  <LogInfo>
    <DetailedProviderTraces>false</DetailedProviderTraces>
    <SyncGroupId>6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b</SyncGroupId>
    <SyncGroupMemberIdList />
    <HubDbId>b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847</HubDbId>
    <SyncGroupMemberId>b752dd15-4446-44df-bbc1-17137358308b</SyncGroupMemberId>
    <AgentId>61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9</AgentId>
    <AgentInstanceId>deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93</AgentInstanceId>
    <TracingId>c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e</TracingId>
    <DssServerId>8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57</DssServerId>
    <DatabaseId>306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c</DatabaseId>
    <SqlAzureActivityId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SqlAzureActivityId>
  </LogInfo>
  <ScopeName>5617A034-8229-45FF-AEC5-CA8459D69FE3</ScopeName>
  <SyncGroupMemberId>b752dd15-4446-44df-bbc1-17137358308b</SyncGroupMemberId>
  <LocalDatabaseId>306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c</LocalDatabaseId>
  <RemoteDatabaseId>b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847</RemoteDatabaseId>
  <ConflictResolutionPolicy>LocalWins</ConflictResolutionPolicy>
  <SyncDirection>UploadAndDownload</SyncDirection>
  <SqlSyncProviderBatchSizeInMB>24</SqlSyncProviderBatchSizeInMB>
  <SqlSyncProviderMATSizeInMB>25</SqlSyncProviderMATSizeInMB>
  <SqlSyncProviderMatRowCount>50000</SqlSyncProviderMatRowCount>
</SyncRequest>
DatabaseProvider 8/4/2014 17:25:25  id:DbProvider_EnumChanges_CompleteEnumForAllTables, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, syncGroupMemberId:b752dd15-4446-44df-bbc1-17137358308b, hubDbId:b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, databaseId:306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c, sqlAzureActivityId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, totalBatches:0
DatabaseProvider 8/4/2014 17:25:25  id:DbProvider_EnumChanges_NewBatchAvailable, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, syncGroupMemberId:b752dd15-4446-44df-bbc1-17137358308b, hubDbId:b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, databaseId:306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c, sqlAzureActivityId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, totalBatchesSpooled:1, batchDetails:
        Version                   :3.1
        BatchId                   :b92ea06f-119b-405e-b2af-29a2ae0f06b6
        Batch Number              :1
        Is Last Batch             :True
        Data Cache Size           :215149
        Table Watermarks          :[dbo.ItemMaster,181071],[dbo.ItemShopDetail,175347],[dbo.ShopWorkdayDetail,180602],[dbo.OclClientXFileUpload,178442],[dbo.ReportTurnoverHeader,178386],[dbo.ReportTurnoverDetail,178440],[dbo.ShopWorkdayPeriodDetail,178470],[dbo.TableMaster,178667],[dbo.Roster,178683],[dbo.TxSalesHeader,178346],[dbo.MemberTxLog,174510],[dbo.TxPayment,178342],[dbo.TxSalesDetail,178221],[dbo.RawMaterialTxSalesDetail,178213],[dbo.TxSalesDetailLog,178215],[dbo.TxSalesHeaderLog,178343],[dbo.TxSalesHeaderRevokeLog,174128],
SyncController 8/4/2014 17:25:25  id:SyncController_BatchSpooledEvent, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, memberDbId:306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c, hubDbId:b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847, currentBatchNumber:1, totalBatchesSpooled:1, batchFileName:b92ea06f-119b-405e-b2af-29a2ae0f06b6.batch
BatchTransferUtil 8/4/2014 17:25:26  id:BatchTransfer_ClientInitialized, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
BatchTransferUtil 8/4/2014 17:25:26  id:BatchTransfer_Start, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
LocalAgentHost 8/4/2014 17:25:27  id:LocalAgentHost_Info, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, traceLevel:Info, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, version:4.0.89.0, methodName:ClientUXService.PingDss, message:Successfully pinged SQL Data Sync.
LocalAgentHost 8/4/2014 17:25:27  id:LocalAgentHost_Info, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, traceLevel:Info, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, version:4.0.89.0, methodName:ClientUXService.PingDss, message:Successfully pinged SQL Data Sync.
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
BatchTransferUtil 8/4/2014 17:25:41  id:BatchTransfer_ClientInitialized, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
BatchTransferUtil 8/4/2014 17:25:41  id:BatchTransfer_Start, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
SyncController 8/4/2014 17:25:41  id:SyncController_BatchAppliedEvent, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, memberDbId:306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c, hubDbId:b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847, currentBatchNumber:1, totalBatches:1
DatabaseProvider 8/4/2014 17:25:41  id:DbProvider_MAT_AllBatchesApplied, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, syncGroupMemberId:b752dd15-4446-44df-bbc1-17137358308b, hubDbId:b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847, tracingId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, databaseId:306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c, sqlAzureActivityId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, madeWithKnowledge:ReplicaKeyMap: [(0:dcc55513c3b54ba7b48aa7a321bb9cae) (1:1f1d55f265144dcd92a9f3950d11f2b8)] ScopeRangeSet: [00:[(0:642383) (1:172822)]], madeWithForgottenKnowledge:ReplicaKeyMap: [(0:dcc55513c3b54ba7b48aa7a321bb9cae) (1:1f1d55f265144dcd92a9f3950d11f2b8)] ScopeRangeSet: [00:[]], totalChanges:0, totalChangesApplied:0, totalChangesFailed:0, totalChangesPending:0, totalInserts:0, totalUpdates:0, totalDeletes:0
SyncController_SyncStatistics 8/4/2014 17:25:42  id:SyncController_SyncStatistics, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, taskId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, syncGroupId:6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b, memberDbId:306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c, hubDbId:b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847, DownloadChangesApplied:0, DownloadChangesFailed:0, DownloadChangesTotal:0, UploadChangesApplied:0, UploadChangesFailed:0, UploadChangesTotal:0, SyncStartTime:9/4/2014 1:25:21, SyncEndTime:9/4/2014 1:25:42
ClientRequestHandler 8/4/2014 17:25:42  id:ClientRequestHandler_Response, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, taskId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e, serializedResponse:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SyncResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <State>Succeeded</State>
  <LogInfo>
    <DetailedProviderTraces>false</DetailedProviderTraces>
    <SyncGroupId>6e4af9cd-765b-4684-96c3-379972dfb36b</SyncGroupId>
    <SyncGroupMemberIdList />
    <HubDbId>b77516b0-7ce9-4519-99d0-1cd829224847</HubDbId>
    <SyncGroupMemberId>b752dd15-4446-44df-bbc1-17137358308b</SyncGroupMemberId>
    <AgentId>61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9</AgentId>
    <AgentInstanceId>deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93</AgentInstanceId>
    <TracingId>c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e</TracingId>
    <DssServerId>8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57</DssServerId>
    <DatabaseId>306e351c-9bd3-4b8d-bc94-c5ff7273301c</DatabaseId>
    <SqlAzureActivityId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SqlAzureActivityId>
  </LogInfo>
  <FailureLog />
  <PostActionSucceededWork xsi:nil="true" />
  <SyncGroupMemberId>b752dd15-4446-44df-bbc1-17137358308b</SyncGroupMemberId>
  <DownloadChangesTotal>0</DownloadChangesTotal>
  <DownloadChangesApplied>0</DownloadChangesApplied>
  <DownloadChangesFailed>0</DownloadChangesFailed>
  <UploadChangesTotal>0</UploadChangesTotal>
  <UploadChangesApplied>0</UploadChangesApplied>
  <UploadChangesFailed>0</UploadChangesFailed>
  <StartTime>2014-04-08T17:25:21.7525842Z</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2014-04-08T17:25:42.0170198Z</EndTime>
  <FailureType>None</FailureType>
</SyncResponse>
CommandAndControlClient 8/4/2014 17:25:42  id:CommandAndControlClient_RequestProcessedSuccessfully, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, taskId:c1d40bea-fe02-49c6-8e0b-80084128121e
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:20. GetRequest started.
LocalAgentHost 8/4/2014 17:25:42  id:LocalAgentHost_Info, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, traceLevel:Info, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, version:4.0.89.0, methodName:ClientUXService.PingDss, message:Successfully pinged SQL Data Sync.
LocalAgentHost 8/4/2014 17:25:42  id:LocalAgentHost_Info, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, traceLevel:Info, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, version:4.0.89.0, methodName:ClientUXService.PingDss, message:Successfully pinged SQL Data Sync.
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
LocalAgentHost 8/4/2014 17:25:57  id:LocalAgentHost_Info, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, traceLevel:Info, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, version:4.0.89.0, methodName:ClientUXService.PingDss, message:Successfully pinged SQL Data Sync.
LocalAgentHost 8/4/2014 17:25:57  id:LocalAgentHost_Info, rId:, sId:8646bcc4-d96e-4b4d-814b-93abd0b5ba57, traceLevel:Info, agentId:61dba401-b646-4108-ba6b-b06bbccacee9, agentInstanceId:deb2662a-482c-440a-90dd-6e4c340a4c93, version:4.0.89.0, methodName:ClientUXService.PingDss, message:Successfully pinged SQL Data Sync.
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
ThreadId:19. Dispatcher calling GetRequest
```

Comment: when you a do a change locally,do you see the corresponding entry in the _tracking table updated?

Comment: @JuneT Yes, I can see in the _tracking table that the last_change_datetime is "2014-04-08 22:24:07.367" on client side, but on the server side, the "last_change_datetime" of last record is "2014-04-08 05:47:12.713"

Comment: look at the update timestamp instead of the date.

Comment: @JuneT Yes, as those records are newly created, I can see the corresponding _tracking table have that newly added row. The Client side sync log seems no error, I am thinking if the server side has error and rolled back, but I cannot check that from the Azure Portal

Comment: I've tried to update the same table on Azure SQL DB, it can sync the changes downwards successfully, however I modify the same records, it cannot sync upwards.